# Why does .event.set("fieldName", ObjectValue) not storing any data in Google Calendar API android?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I successfully intergarted Google Calendar API. I'm able to do CRUD. But now because of some requirements, I want to send some unique id to each events while creating from android app. For that I found one method called `.set()` this is a key value pair.

```
 Event event = new Event()
                    .set("appointment_id", 55475)
                    .setSummary(summary)
                    .setLocation(location)
                    .setDescription(des);
```

But while fetching, I'm getting all data except `event.get("appointment_id")`

Why, even it is setting also. [If I'm doing here before executing insert like this: `evetn.get("appointment_id")`, I'm getting value, because this is locally I'm chocking]

I checked through debugging as well. See below:

[image]

**But, I'm not getting when I'm fetching all events from Google calendar:**

```
List<Event> items = events.getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`set`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/Event.html#set-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) method, but this is just an override of the `com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson` class, I believe this will only add this key-value to the final JSON which will be ignored by the API (as it is not an expected field).

Sincerely I don't know what is the point on creating a custom id when there is one directly integrated in calendar.

If you take a look at the [`insert`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) method you can see that there is one field called [`id`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#id):

> Opaque identifier of the event. When creating new single or recurring events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs must follow these rules:
>
> - characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in RFC2938
> - the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
> - the ID must be unique per calendar

Also in the same description for the field:

> If you do not specify an ID, it will be automatically generated by the server.

My point being that if you need unique ID for events in calendar there is a built in method that will create them for you. And even if you need to supply your own id's you can do so informing this field.

Let me suggest you the official guide on [event creation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#metadata) in which there is a more detailed view on the option you can take creating an Event.

Also look at the documentation for [`setId`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/Event.html#setId-java.lang.String-) as this is the method you should be using instead of `set`.

---

Example:

```java
Event event = new Event()
                    .setId("55475") // This has to be type String
                    .setSummary(summary)
                    .setLocation(location)
                    .setDescription(des);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also know that I'll get unique Id, then why I'm asking this question here, obviously because of some requirements or dependency. So, I have dependency that appointment id I'm getting from server, and with that id Ive to set and get. And there is no possibility to crete/modify column from server side. But one thing I'll try that I'll setId as a appointment id, so that later I can identify. let me chk

Comment: I tried but the thing is after Id it is attaching like this: _20200512T175800Z ; I don't want that

Comment: my requirement is I want to chk first before creating event that whether any event is there in Google calendar with that appointment id? because in my server appointment id is unique. So what I was thinking I using for loop I'll fetch all event and in that I'll chk id with my server apmnt id

Comment: I sent this: 97145   and I got this: 97145_20200512T175800Z

Comment: So is it fine if I'll take char before _ using some string logic? so that I'll get my exact apmnt id?

Comment: I have tested this and providing the id works and does not attach nothing at the end. Is straight the id you provide them, of course in the case you actually provide a unique event id in said calendar. I mean you can manage to make it work, but the API will not add a trailing date to your ID, at least is not doing for me.

Comment: it is adding date behind our created id